# Solarized dark pdfs?

Tags: linux-mint, pdf, software-rec

I'd like to know if there is a pdf reader with the option to select a colour scheme? Particularly solarized dark.

Comment: You may be interested in pdf viewers that can do "reverse-video", which can make documents more readable. I know of `xpdf` and `evince`.

Comment: I do not like white on black background, I prefer a light grey on dark grey if solarized is not an option. I know I've seen dark grey pdfs before but I don't remember where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked out [Zathura](https://github.com/lennonwoo/zathura-solarized)?

It supports a solarized dark theme which you can set up as follows:

```
sudo apt install -y zathura
mkdir -p ~/.config/zathura
wget "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lennonwoo/zathura-solarized/master/zathura-solarized-dark" -O ~/.config/zathura/zathurarc
```